# MIPS passing two arguments and saving it

Tags: c, mips

I have the following code in C

```
int bitIndex = hash_str(input, i);
```

`hash_str` is just a function that I call. `input` is a pointer to a `char` and `i` a standard integer.

I'd like to implement this function in MIPS. I've determined that `input` = `$a0` and `i` = `$s0` (I've saved `$s0` on the stack already).

Conventional wisdom tells me when it comes to calling functions I'd just

```
ARG I
ARG II
jal LABEL
```

My dilemma here is that `$a0` and `$s0` already 'exist', so how do I call the `hash_str` function with them? Furthermore, how do I store that in an integer all in MIPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C compiler will follow the standard calling conventions, though may have some options for different behavior.

Generally speaking first `int` or pointer type parameter goes in `$a0`, second in `$a1`, third in `$a2`, fourth in `$a3`.  `int` or pointer type return values goes into `$v0`.

The order of populating the registers doesn't matter as long as the right values have been placed in the right registers before the call instruction (`jal`).  So, you can first put argument 2 in `$a1`, then next put argument 1 in `$a0`, and it will still work the same.

For more information see here: https://www.dyncall.org/docs/manual/manualse11.html and scroll down to your architecture & ABI.